# 1 byte 8 bit encoding

Tags: c#, .net, encoding, character-encoding, .net-core-3.1

I need to create `System.String` from file with some unknown ASCII-compatible 1-byte encoding to replace some numbers in text with regex, but `Encoding.ASCII` is 7-bit, and Utf-8 is multi-byte so it won't round-trip back to same byte sequence.

Is there encoding in .Net Core which can round-trip any byte sequence?

UPD: [Windows-1256 Character set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1256#Character_set) looks promising, but it Windows only.

Comment: Can you give an example of what you want? The internal representation of System.String is Unicode, so Encoding.Unicode will round-trip perfectly, but it's not an 1-byte encoding, of course.

Comment: @PMF I have non unicode unknown input and I want to use RegEx to manipulate this data, but it works only with System.String. And then convert it back to same byte sequence (except regex replaces I made)

Comment: @PMF Unicode has surrogate pairs, so some byte sequences are illegal for unicode

Comment: So your input is actually binary? Then don't use RegEx, it's not intended for that.

Comment: a byte array? a span?

Comment: @PMF it's some windows codepage (different for each file), all of them are ASCII-compatible

Comment: @DanielA.White Irrelevant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `ISO-8859-1` will map directly to [Latin-1 Supplement Unicode block](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin-1_Supplement_(Unicode_block)) and back again (roundtrip). And it is one of encodings .NET Core [supports](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.codepagesencodingprovider.instance?view=net-5.0) by default.

```
// C#
var enc = Encoding.GetEncoding(28591); // ISO-8859-1 (code page 28591)
var b = Enumerable.Range(0, 0xFF + 1).Select(x => (byte)x).ToArray();
    
enc.GetBytes(enc.GetString(b)).SequenceEqual(b) == true
```

More over each `char` will have equivalent `byte` value

```
// F#
let bytes = [| Byte.MinValue .. Byte.MaxValue |]
let chars = Encoding.Latin1.GetChars bytes
Array.map byte chars = bytes

val it: bool = true
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, if you don't know the encoding, using the string is more a hack than a solution. I guess it can be quicker and possibly easier, but for more robust and clean solution, I'd just work on byte[] or something similar. String would be fine, if it's use-once solution.

If you really want to use strings here, I'd suggest looking into all encodings from windows/cp family or ISO 8859 family. E.g. on my PC, I can use `iso-8859-1`. `Windows 1256` would also be fine, on Linux is often called `cp 1256` (CP for Code Page).

However, you are not guaranteed to have that encoding supported on all platforms, AFAIK .NET guarantees only UTFs and Unicode. If you want to have this encoding available everywhere, consider using nuget package like this: https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Text.Encoding.CodePages/

Comment: iso-8859-1 have unmapped ranges 0-16,128-144 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1#Code_page_layout

Comment: Regex and Encoding libraries have SIMD acceleration and other quality-of-life/quality-of-implementation features which my custom made solution will lack

Comment: The best I can think of is to implement custom encoding that will map each `byte > 127` to some random, but valid Unicode code point, so I can use regex. I have a bad feeling about using cp1256 cause it contains arabic symbols, so it could trigger some RTL handling.

Comment: Yes, you're right, ISO won't work, only Windows/CP. If you don't want Windows 1256, due to RTL, you can use e.g. 1250 (it has some central European ąęść etc., popular in Poland).

I guess RTL shouldn't be a problem as long as you don't display it.

Comment: Your own encoding is also a solution, probably cleaner than using some irrelevant encoding just to have mapping and also you don't need a nuget package

Anyway, as for acceleration - converting the binary into string (which increases its size twice) and back to byte[] has also some cost, so it's not given that Regex with SIMD acceleration will be faster

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1250 have 5 unmapped bytes.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1251 looks better with only `0x98` unmapped.
And `Encoding.GetEncoding(1251).GetString(new byte[] { 0x98 }) == "\u0098"`
Unicode Character `START OF STRING` which looks like regular non-printable char

Comment: I actually tried iso-8859-1, and it works good. Up voted your suggestion.